# Can't install amdgpu-pro 18.40 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, amdgpu-pro

I'm trying to install `amdgpu-pro-18.40` on my fresh Ubuntu 20.04, since with the vanilla gpu driver I see movies in slow motion on my home TV.  but I get this error:

```
# ./amdgpu-install 
deb [ trusted=yes ] file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/ ./
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
Ign:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
Hit:4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:5 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Package: *amdgpu*
Pin: release o=AMD
Pin: version *-697810
Pin-Priority: 1000

Package: *amdgpu*:i386
Pin: release o=AMD
Pin: version *-697810
Pin-Priority: 1000

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu : Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-client0 (= 1.14.0-697810) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-server0 (= 1.14.0-697810) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libgbm1-amdgpu (= 1:18.1.0-697810) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa (= 1:18.1.0-697810) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers (= 1:18.1.0-697810) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-egl1-mesa (= 1:18.1.0-697810) but it is not going to be installed
 amdgpu-lib32 : Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-client0:i386 (= 1.14.0-697810)
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-server0:i386 (= 1.14.0-697810)
                Depends: libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:18.1.0-697810)
                Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.1.0-697810)
                Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (= 1:18.1.0-697810)
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-egl1-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.1.0-697810)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

My GPU is  Radeon Rx580 8GB

I have looked at similar questions and tried installing with other flags like `--px` and `--compute` as suggested but none works.

Apperently this issue is resolved here:
https://community.amd.com/t5/drivers-software/can-t-install-amdgpu-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-1-5-4-0-56-generic/td-p/426676/page/19
But I could not follow 20 pages of back and forth and figure out how.

So appreciate your hints.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Which one is suposed to answer my question? I did all the usual stuff, like `install -f` and so on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid these kind of issues you cant install the appropriate package for
your current version :

This is in AMD website:
https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-6000-series/amd-radeon-6900-series/amd-radeon-rx-6900-xt

Radeon™ Software for Linux® installer version 22.10.2 for Ubuntu 20.04.4